# Php include head with a link to the css dont work

Tags: php, html, css, require, head

I have started to use php a little bit. And got the first problem, which I can't get rid of. I want my `index.php` with this code(in the head section):

```
<head>
<?php
    require 'php/main/head.html';
?>
</head>
```

get access to my `head.html` with this code:

```
<link href="../../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../style/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../../style/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://www.mike-kaufmann.de/global/current_year.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text.css">
<link href="../../img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
// and more code..
```

The first link should "normally" get the information from the `style.css`, but it don't take anything. Like it is a wrong path.

The code in the css should do some margin to an element in the `index.php`; but i said before, it don't do anything.

My question is now: **How/ What i have todo to get access to my style.css**;

If the code is hard to read you can download it and test it yourself:
[Dropbox-link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nxeo0r71jbhxfaw/AABEOdf4GRCL-PpTmPcZzExCa?dl=0) or view it on my [Github Repo](https://github.com/mkmike000/Last-Death) and upload some changes there.

**Question:** I´ve read that the include function lets the user load the website every time again. Means it don't uses the cache. Is that true? If it is, what can i use instead for good web performance?

Thanks for all answers.

Greetings Mike. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is now: How/ What i have todo to get access to my
>   style.css;

You did everything right:

```
<meta name="description" content="#"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="#"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Last Death" />
<meta name="author" content="Mike Kaufmann"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>

<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://www.mike-kaufmann.de/global/current_year.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text.css">
<link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.site-check.cc/files/themen/zoom/vorschaubild.jpg"/> <!--Für Facebook links-->
```

**except** this code `type="text.css"` should be `type="text/css"`

> I´ve read that the include function lets the user load the website
>   every time again. Means it don't uses the cache. Is that true? If it
>   is, what can i use instead for good web performance?

Yes it is try. But don't be stressed about performance on 3-5 includes. Modern php frameworks usually have much more includes.

But if you still want to reduce `includes` load impact then place `footer`,`head` and `header`  to one `layout.php` and lets `layout.php` then  include dynamic `php` part.

Comment: Hi, ive tried this already. It dont work, and that is my problem... i dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

As per your [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mkmike000/Last-Death), the `style` directory is in the same level of hierarchy as your `index.php` file so using `../../` is unnecessary. A `../` denotes level-up from current directory the script resides in. Remove `../../` from all of your assets and they'll start working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`../` is essentially indicating to go one directory up in the directory tree. Looking at your github repo all you need to do is change your

`<link href="../../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` to 
`<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my fault. I didn´t started my Server -.- I am a idiot.